# Can't append Column Names of Dataframe To A List Using For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a Dataframe like this:-

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['q', 'r', 's', 't'],['n'],['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Full_1', 'Full_2', 'Full_3', 'Full_4'])
```

Now I want to append the columns of a dataframe which contains 'None' value using for `loop` inside a function

```
lst=[]
def lister(df):
    for c in df.columns:
        if (df[c].isna().max())==True:
            lst.append(c)
            return lst
        else:
            nope = 'None'
            return nope
```

It returns me 'None' `intsead` of `lst`

Now If I print `c` Inside of `for loop` i.e

```
lst=[]
def lister(df):
    for c in df.columns:
        if (df[c].isna().max())==True:

            print(c)
            #return lst
        else:
            nope = 'None'
            #return nope
```

Output of `c` inside `for` loop:-

```
Full_2
Full_3
Full_4
```

So Why these values not appending in list named lst?

Expected output of `lst`:-

```
['Full_2','Full_3','Full_4']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> df.columns[df.isna().any()].to_list()
['Full_2', 'Full_3', 'Full_4']
```

**Edit**: update your function like this.

```
def lister(df):
    lst = []
    for c in df.columns:
        if (df[c].isna().max()) == True:
            lst.append(c)
    return lst
```

```
>>> lister(df)
['Full_2', 'Full_3', 'Full_4']
```

Comment: hey!I just change question little bit...have a look

Comment: do you really want to use a loop?

Comment: yes i want to use for loop that's why i am having issues

Comment: What about `else` part?@Corralien

Comment: what do you want to do with `else` part. `nope = None` is useless if you do nothing with the variable `nope`.

Comment: so why it is returning nope' instead of list?and not appending values inside list?@Corralien..........btw just give this answer and I will accept your answer

Comment: `return` breaks the loop when `c` equals `'Full_1'` because `df[c].isna().max()) != True`. The `return` statement should be used at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You're initialising the list every time.

So it resets to an empty list inside the if statement.

Move your `lst=[]` line outside of the for loop.

Comment: hey!I just change question little bit...have a look...btw your solution it doesn't work